# Comparative Histograms Separated by Factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

Have an assignment where we need to provide one-dimensional graphs for EDA but the sample code given answers most of the requirements already (simple scatter and box plots and a histogram) so I am trying to "spice it up" a little by creating some more interesting graphs. Only need a couple.

The data set is the twin IQ data across several studies/authors and I was wanting to do a back-to-back histogram of the twins separated by author. So far I can do an overlay of authors *or* the back to back of the twins using ggplot but I am then stuck when trying to separate in to either 4 graphs or overlaid back-to-backs.

The code I was using for the overlay was ggplot with either geom_density or geom_histogram and the code for the back-to-back came from [R-Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-back-to-back-histograms/) and I used the first snippet:

```
ggplot(df, aes(IQ)) + geom_histogram(aes(x = x1, y = ..density..), fill = "blue") + geom_histogram( aes(x = x2, y = -..density..), fill = "green")
```

What I am looking for is a way to combine these two techniques or how to get ggplot to split the graphs up by factor in much the same was as plot/lattice does when you do, for example:

```
bwplot(y~x1.x2|Author, data=df)
```

Comment: look into facet_grid() or facet_wrap()

Comment: ... `+ facet_grid(~split_factor)`

Comment: … but, isn't it _your_ assignment?

Comment: At least he or she specified that it was an assignment.

Comment: It is why I specified it was an assignment as I am aware of the rules around here. I can answer with the sample code given in the assignment and what I have so far is also sufficient but I am trying to extend myself but can't figure this next step out myself.

Comment: The phrase back-to-back makes me wonder if you want a pyramid-plot?

Comment: Using histograms but looking at pyramid plots seems like they would be appropriate too. Interesting because I am heading in to 3rd year stats and hadn't heard of them until now :)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet that I am using to achieve separate plots includes `facet_grid()` such that the final code is:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y)) + facet_grid(~Author) + geom_histogram(aes(x = x1, y = ..density..), fill = "green") + geom_histogram(aes(x = x2, y = -..density..), fill = "blue")
```

I wasn't previously aware of the facet_grid() function of ggplot so thank you very much to MLavoie and Brandon Bertelsen.